# expo never end ,keeps blinking downloading java-script bundle

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

```
expo start
```

when it run and open on phone or emulator , it keeps

> Downloading JavaScript bundle

and it never ends ,and the app blinks for less than 1 second
I tried

> expo start -c

didn't work
help!

Comment: Try run “exp start --localhost”. There is also a “–lan” flag.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for your suggestions, I answered my question, check it, thanks again for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in react-native-gesture-handler

I had a newer version and it needed and old version so i run

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0
```

I will keep the question, hope it will help someone.